# Ошибка при AJAX загрузке файлов

Tags: octobercms

Делаю по аналогии с https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YU6I-VKW39g
Форма:

```
<form class="comment_form" data-request="onSubmit" data-request-files data-request-flash>
<input type="hidden" name="_handler" value="onSave">

            {{ form_token() }}

            {{ form_sessionkey() }}
...
<input type="file" name="commentimage" accept="image/*" data-request="onImageUpload" data-request-files data-request-flash>
</form>
```

Модель:

```
use System\Models\File;
class Comments extends Model
{
...
public $attachOne = [
        'commentimage' => 'System\Models\File'
    ];
}
```

Загрузчик:

```
use System\Models\File;
use Input;
use Flash;
use Response;
class Comments extends ComponentBase
{
...
public function onImageUpload(){
        $image = Input::all();
        $file = (new File())->fromPost($image('commentimage'));// line 217
        return [
            '#imageResult' => 'img src="' . $file->getThumb(200,200,['mode'=>'crop']) . '">'
        ];
    }
}
```

У меня выдаёт ошибку:
"Function name must be a string" on line 217

Что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file = (new File())->fromPost($image['commentimage']);
```

Вот так правильно. 
Для массива используются квадратные скобки.